# How do i xor two arrays of bits so that i can find out the errors that have been added using a binary symmetric channel

Tags: python, binary, signal-processing

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Feb  5 12:02:55 2021
@author: Sam
"""
'Libraries'
import komm as komm
#import numpy as np 
#from math import pi 
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib as np

#Varibles
x = [0,1,0,0,1,1]
pam = komm.PAModulation(4, base_amplitude=1.0)      
awgn = komm.AWGNChannel(snr=100.0, signal_power=1.0) 'Noise channel'
bsc = komm.BinarySymmetricChannel(0.1)              'Binary symmetric channel'
y = awgn(x); y                                      'Adding noise to x array'
z = bsc(x); z                                       'BSC applied to x array'


#Main code:
data_tx = pam.modulate(x)
data_rx = pam.demodulate(data_tx)

#data_tx2 = pam.modulate(y)


print ('PAM modulated data is: ',data_tx)
print ('Demodulated data is:   ',data_rx)
print ('Array with noise added is: ',y)
print ('Channel capacity is: ',awgn.capacity())

print(z)


data1 = sum(XOR(x,z))

#print (pam.constellation)
#print (pam.energy_per_bit)
```

This is the code that i have currently, and on line 37 "data1 = sum(XOR(x,z))" i want to be able to XOR both of these arrays is there a built in XOR function or a library that allows this to work.
or how would i set it up by just using for loops to go through each index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

[`bsc()`](https://komm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/komm/_channels/#BinarySymmetricChannel) returns a numpy array. You simply need
[`numpy.bitwise_xor()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html), or the standard Python XOR syntax, `^`.

```
x = np.array(x)
data1 = sum(x ^ z)
```